# Zend Framework modular app, can't load models for each module, autoloading models?

Tags: zend-framework, model, module

Is there a way to have models for each module? I have 3 modules, one is a "contacts" module.
I created a model for it in modules/contacts/models/Codes.php
**Codes Controller**

```
class Contacts_CodesController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    $this->view->messages = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages();  

    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

    $codesTable = new Contacts_Model_Codes();

    }
```

**Codes Model:**

```
class Contacts_Model_Codes extends Zend_Db_Table
{
    protected $_name = 'codes';
}
```

**The error I get:**
Fatal error: Class 'Contacts_Model_Codes' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zf_site/application/modules/contacts/controllers/CodesController.php on line 26

thanks

Answer (score 18):

I found the problem. I forgot to put a bootstrap file in with my contacts module.
Now it all works and I can have my modules use their own models.

```
class Contacts_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

}
```

Comment: Also add "resources.modules[] =" to your application.ini

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I wonder why both of these things weren't taken care of by "zf create module x". Is there a case where you wouldn't want them?

Answer (score 6):

I've found the solution, I guess! :)
It's a problem when you add the next Resource in the application.ini file

```
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "Default"
```

and also you use some kind of parameters. I think that is a Bug.

The correct way to implement Modules is:

1 - Create your desired modules and the '**Default**' Module with zf tool

2 - In **apllication.ini** tell ZF where the modules are and where the controllers of those modules are, with

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "controllers"
```

Use the known

```
resources.modules = ""
```

And set:

```
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = ""
```

It's important because zf tool set it to "1". Here is the bug. :)

And remember DO NOT PUT WHAT THE DEFAULT MODULE IS!!

3 - Create the bootstrap file for each module and put:

If my module is 'Evacol':

```
<?php
class Evacol_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
}
```

*Save it to /modules/Evacol/* obviously

Take note of **Evacol_**... and ..._**Module_Bootstr**... THE NAME OF MY MODULE EXTENDING THE CORRECT CLASS.
Don't use the default value of bootstrap file created with zf tool. I did it :)

DON'T MODIFY ANYTHING ELSE. IT IS NOT NECESARY.

And voila! Trust me. It works!

**It was Zend Framework 1.10.8**

Answer (score 5):

You have to register the 'Contacts_' namespace with the auto loader. You can use Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader for this.

```
$autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'Contacts_',
        'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__) . '/modules/cotacts',
    ));
```

This will create the following mappings for your module inside the basePath you provide.

```
api/         => Api
forms/       => Form
models/      => Model
    DbTable/ => Model_DbTable
plugins/     => Plugin
```

If you are using Zend_Application to boostrap your application and it' modules you should not need this because the docs say that:

> When using module bootstraps with Zend_Application, an instance of Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader will be created by default for each discrete module, allowing you to autoload module resources.

Comment: This is only true for ZF 1.8, in this version the module autoloader was added and Zend_Application uses it to bootstrap modules.  
In older versions you will need to use Zend_Application_Resource_Modules

Answer (score 5):

add

```
resources.modules[] =
```

To your config ini

Answer (score 2):

I'm using version 1.9.
This is part of my bootstrap:

```
protected function _initAutoload() {
    $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                  'namespace' => '',
                   'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules/default')

        );
}

    protected function _initAutoloaders()
    {
        $this->getApplication()->setAutoloaderNamespaces(array('Eric_'));
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _initPlugins()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('autoloaders');
        $this->bootstrap('frontController');

        // register the plugin for setting layouts per module
        $plugin = new Eric_Plugin_Modularlayout();
        $this->frontController->registerPlugin($plugin);
            return $modelLoader;
    }
```

The plugin Eric_Plugin_Modularlayout sets the correct layout for each module.

I have 3 modules: default, ez, contacts.
The funny thing is, In a contacts action I can call the models in the ez/models dir. without a problem.